# Set up JMX support using LocalSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, hibernate, jmx, jconsole

There is java configuration bean with Hibernate JMX Statistics Service and `LocalSessionFactoryBean` configurations. I don't see any possibility to get SessionFactory through already instantiated `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. The goal is to enable JMX support so JConsole would be able to access Hibernates statistics. If I create new SessionFactory it will be duplicate. How to proceed with this configuration?

```
 @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(){
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
        // JMX statistics
        SessionFactory sf = ...; // ???
        StatisticsService statsMBean = new StatisticsService();
        statsMBean.setSessionFactory(sessionFactoryBean.);
        statsMBean.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

        MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        mBeanServer.registerMBean(statsMBean, new ObjectName("Hibernate:application=Statistics"));

        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }
```

[JConsole](http://hibernate-jcons.sourceforge.net/usage.html#pre-requisites)

Comment: Your edit is not related to your original question. Don't do that. If you have a new question about classpath issues, ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Write a new `@Bean` method to expose the `StatisticsService`

```
@Autowired
@Bean
public StatisticsService service(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    StatisticsService statsMBean = new StatisticsService();
    statsMBean.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
    statsMBean.setStatisticsEnabled(true);

    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    mBeanServer.registerMBean(statsMBean, new ObjectName("Hibernate:application=Statistics"));
    return statsMBean;
}
```

Alternatively, you can invoke `afterPropertiesSet` and `getObject` on `sessionFactoryBean` to get the `SessionFactory` instance. Note that you will have to check if `getObject` returns the same object on future invocations. You don't want it to return one instance for use with your MBean and another instance for the rest of your app.

Comment: Actually `sessionFactory`method has one more annotation: `@DependsOn("flyway")`. Will it interfere with `StatisticsService ` bean? What kind of type will work for `ObjectName`. I tried: `javax.mamagement.ObjectName` and `org.hibernate.metamodelrelational.ObjectName` but IDE refuses to work with those.

Comment: @RCola No, the `@DependsOn` will have no effect here. It will simply force the `flyway` bean to be prepared before both the `StatisticsService` and `LocalSessionFactoryBean` (and `SessionFactory`) beans.

Comment: For `ObjectName`, I would assume the `javax` version, but you need the appropriate libraries.

Comment: I got error `Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.hibernate.jmx.StatisticsService]: Factory method 'service' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/stat/StatisticsImpl`

Comment: @RCola [Fix your classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java).